# Xamarin iOS app not call web API in production

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have published an iOS app to the Apple TestFlight section built with Xamarin.
This application call a web API through the http protocol to authorize an user.
Testing it with the emulator on a macbook build host (the app is write in Windows with Visual Studio 2015) it works perfectly. After the publish it display the Launch Screen, the login view but pressing the button to login the user, it return immediately the message with the login failure. It seems that it doesn't try to connect to the web API but return false immediately.

On the app publish wizard, it told me to add this tag to the `info.plist` because I don't use any encryption.

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>
```

This is the code to call the web API:

```
public async Task<T> GetEntity<T>(string action, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> body) where T : class
{

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(_serverUri, action) };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

    var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaType);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);

    var result = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;

    if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return null;


    var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);

    return entity;

}
```

Probably the `result.IsSuccessStatusCode` property return false.
I've published the same app to the Android Store and Microsoft Marketplace and all of them works perfectly.

Comment: Sounds similar to ATS requirements: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/#Default_ATS_Behavior | Because ATS is enabled by default in iOS 9 and OS X El Capitan, if your Xamarin.iOS app or any library or service it is using makes connection to the internet, you'll need to take some action or your connections will result in an exception being thrown.

Comment: I tried to disable ATS into the Info.plist but it doesn't work

Comment: Indeed, looks like ATS. Is the url HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: HTTP but I tried with HTTPS too. Both not connect.